# auto generate report(weekly and monthly)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Does anyone know how to schedule auto-generate for weekly and monthly report? I tried to use Windows Service,but the problem is I don't know how to setup my report to auto generate for weekly and monthly report. At this moment, I just put the date at the setparametervalue only. would appreciate if someone can guide me about this and do refer below for my coding. Thanks.

```
    private Timer scheduleTimer = null;
    private DateTime lastRun;
    private bool flag;

    static TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo;
    static ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo;
    static Tables crTables;
    static Database crDatabase;

    static string Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverName"];
    static string Database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];
    static string UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userID"];
    static string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

    public ReportWindowsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        scheduleTimer = new Timer();
        scheduleTimer.Interval = 1 * 5 * 60 * 1000;
        scheduleTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(scheduleTimer_Elapsed);

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to start your service.
        flag = true;
        lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        scheduleTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void scheduleTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == true)
        {
            BillingReport();
            ReleaseImageReport();
            lastRun = DateTime.Now;
            flag = false;
        }
        else if (flag == false)
        {
            if (lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                BillingReport();
                ReleaseImageReport();
            }
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionInfo ReportLogin(ReportDocument crRpt)
    {
        crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Server;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Database;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = UserID;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;

        crDatabase = crRpt.Database;
        crTables = crDatabase.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
        {
            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
        }

        return crConnectionInfo;
    }

    public static void BillingReport()//monthly report
    {
        ReportDocument crRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crRpt.Load("C:\\rptBilling.rpt");

        ReportLogin(crRpt);

        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@CollectionStartDate", "2011/09/14");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@CollectionEndDate", "2011/09/29");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@SpokeCode", "14");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UseCollectionDate", "1");//value can be set 0 or 1
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UseUploadDate", "0");//value can be set 0 or 1
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UploadStartDate", "2011/09/23");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UploadEndDate", "2011/09/23");

        crRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "e:\\BillingReport.pdf");
    }

    public static void ReleaseImageReport()//weekly report
    {
        ReportDocument crRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crRpt.Load("C:\\rptReleaseImage.rpt");

        ReportLogin(crRpt);

        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@CollectionStartDate", "2011/09/14");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@CollectionEndDate", "2011/09/29");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@SpokeCode", "14");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UseCollectionDate", "1");//value can be set 0 or 1
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UseUploadDate", "0");//value can be set 0 or 1
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UploadStartDate", "2011/09/23");
        crRpt.SetParameterValue("@UploadEndDate", "2011/09/23");

        crRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "e:\\ReleaseImageReport.pdf");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        scheduleTimer.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the windows task scheduler with a console application receiving weekly or monthly as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`SQL-JOB`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) to start at periodic Date-Time and [**`run the exe`**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xyprocedure.aspx).

1. In this case you can send your **`Query parameter`** as *`Run-time Parameter`*.
2. Also your must **`write an App`** to get parameter and *`Run report based on input parameter and then Save it`*.

Comment: Hi Rev..thanks for the suggestion..let me try first coz i'm not really gud in sql. If u have any other suggestion like put the scheduler code in c# directly would be appreciate..

Comment: Sql-job is better than Any C# code(in this case Windows services). cuz job active until your server and sql server is running. and scheduling in jop (calling them in periodic time ), is much easier than window's service.